# iOS Persist view layer value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an application where a user can drag many images onto a canvas.  Some views are above other views.  I want to save the images transforms, frames, and z-index.  Where do I find the z-index of a view (in comparison with other views on the superview) so I can persist it.  And then how to I restore all subviews to their proper z-index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The superview have an array of child, into which the child are in order from back 0 to top (number of child) and there is method to insert child at a certain index.

There is a section of method in the UIView documentation with method that look like this one:

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

Answer (score 1):

Look like you are looking for the (set/get) `zPosition` of the views layer.

Comment: Thanks. So do all objects within a certain superview have a zPosition that corresponds with the other objects in the superview?

Comment: zPosition is a layer property, so you can access them in something like view.layer, and will works on any view sibiling, remember that any view has at least one layer.